# Retrieving multiple data from friebase database to recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I know this might going to be a dumb question but I’m having some issues with the firebase real time database in recycle viewer. It either gives me an error message or just simply doesn’t refresh. However when I add the data manually it’s working. I’ve read tons of problem solving articles but I still can’t solve the problem. I hope you guys can help somehow.

Heres my database:
[database link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHSsO.png)

And here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView reciclerView;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> result;
private DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private ListItem model = new ListItem();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    reciclerView = findViewById(R.id.reciclerViewID);
    reciclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    reciclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    result = new ArrayList<>();



myRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model = postSnapshot.getValue(ListItem.class);
                    result.add(model);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    /*model.setName("Johhny");
    model.setEmail("Johhny@gmail.com");
    model.setImageurl("https://uniqlo.scene7.com/is/image/UNIQLO/goods_04_172340?$detail$");*/


    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, result);
    reciclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

The ListItem is the model class, and i also have a DetailsActivity.

Comment: Please include the error logs in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  in your `onDataChange` method. You need to call this method after every change in the list that you want the RecyclerView to detect.